# how to auto fill a word document with VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I would like to create a Microsoft Word template that I can have a VB.net project auto fill specific fields in with database values.  My question is how to best go about this with Word.  Should I create a Template and add Fields, Bookmarks, or something else?  I looked at fields but didn't see a way to create custom field names.  Ideally, I would like to create a group of templates that have the same "Field" names that my application can recognize and fill in.  Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: First Idea: Do not use Word directly, use a third party library to read/write it. Word itself is slow and multitasking-error prone.

Comment: If only I had that option :).  I was told to use word.  Thanks though

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbide/thread/1558f560-8ae6-413a-bbc4-aa8d5d912aac this is what you need.

Comment: This might work, Ryan.  Thanks.  If you add this to a response, I can upvote it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace placeholders with formatted text in a Word doc using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945088/how-to-replace-placeholders-with-formatted-text-in-a-word-doc-using-net)

Comment: @jason just added that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you follow the guide on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbide/thread/1558f560-8ae6-413a-bbc4-aa8d5d912aac

Essentially you are going to create a document with placeholders then use VB to open the document and replace those placeholders.